# express-Formidable "Can't set headers after they are sent."

Tags: node.js, express, formidable

i use the module express formidable

when i load a page 2 time i have that on console

```
GET /users 304 6.948 ms - -
GET /users 304 213.344 ms - -
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:489:11)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:496:3)
at ServerResponse.header (/home/neolinux/Encoding-Service/encode-service/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:730:10)
at ServerResponse.contentType (/home/neolinux/Encoding-Service/encode-service/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:558:15)
at ServerResponse.send (/home/neolinux/Encoding-Service/encode-service/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:145:14)
at done (/home/neolinux/Encoding-Service/encode-service/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:967:10)
at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/neolinux/Encoding-Service/encode-service/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:422:12)
at View.exports.__express [as engine] (/home/neolinux/Encoding-Service/encode-service/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:465:11)
at View.render (/home/neolinux/Encoding-Service/encode-service/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:127:8)
at tryRender (/home/neolinux/Encoding-Service/encode-service/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
```

this is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');


var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

const util=require("util");
var app = express();

const formidable = require('express-formidable');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(formidable({
    uploadDir:  path.join(__dirname, '/Upload'),
}));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

you must now, if i remove formidable i don't have the error . Any idea ?

express v 4.5
node v8

don't read the next text, this is just for remove the stackoverflow error !!! i don't know how to add more information for this problem.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution, express-formidable have probleme in middleware version,

there are two of each event handler which means each event is handled twice, leading to two next() calls and hence an exception about headers being set too late.

the solution is in app.js:

```
const formidable = require('formidable');
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm({
        encoding: 'utf-8',
        uploadDir:  path.join(__dirname, '/Upload'),
        multiples: true,
        keepExtensions: true
    })
    form.once('error', console.log)
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        Object.assign(req, {fields, files});
        next();
    })
})
app.use('/', index);
```

Comment: In the `express-formidable` repo, the issue has been fixed since February, but the NPM package isn't updated. Until then, use either `formidable` directly as above or install the specific commit which fixed it: `"github:utatti/express-formidable#9986be6279"`.